# Uint8List to file

Tags: android, flutter, dart, uint8list

I want to convert and upload signature image to rest server and how to be able to upload to the rest server. I try convert to file but i get this error
[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U7yT.png)

[log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBFB3.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to show in the widget

```
Image.memory(your_uin8listBytes)
```

or

```
MemoryImage(your_uin8listBytes)
```

If you are sending the uin8list to firebase storage
you can use

```
putData(your_uin8listBytes)
```

instead of

```
putFile(File)
```

and set metadata

```
 SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/$fileType')
```

Comment: How do I upload to a rest server? because i'm not using firebase

Comment: @ZulfaAssyfa You can upload to rest server through multipart file

MultipartFile.fromBytes(String field, List<int> value, {String? filename, MediaType? contentType})

To know more : https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile-class.html

Upvote the answer if you find useful

Answer (score 1):

To upload uint8List to REST server you can do it with

```
MultipartFile.fromBytes(String field, List<int> value, {String? filename, MediaType? contentType})
```

To know more : [visit here](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile-class.html)